# Unity Rigidbody sitting on top of another Rigidbody does not move with the Rigidbody its sitting on

Tags: unity, physics, rigidbody

I have a mesh with a rigid body that moves back and forth like a platform. Other rigidbodies fall onto the upper surface of this cube. The problem I have is that when the platform rigid body moves the other rigid bodies stay in the position they landed in, they do not move with the cube. Everything else physics wise works.

I have tried adding a physicsmaterial to both the platform and the rigidbodies falling onto the platform but this made no difference.

I do no want to tether them to each other because I want them to fall off when they are pushed by other objects.

The platform is moved back and forth using the RigidBody.MovePosition function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not fully understand why but setting iskinematic to true on the platforms rigidbody gives me the behavior I was after.

Comment: As silly as it sounds, be sure to click the checkmark to accept your own answer as correct.  It helps with maintenance and so that people don't see this listed as an unanswered question.

Comment: It says that I have to wait two days to mark it as the answer.

Comment: Oh duh - right you are.